# SQL subquery,inner query

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the problem here?I use subquery and named it 't',but when run the script ,occurs error like -column ambiguously defined.And there is no any problem at inner query,it is working

```
select * from  
( select d.column_name , k.*, d.* 
  from user_constraints k, user_cons_columns d 
  where k.constraint_name=D.CONSTRAINT_NAME
    and D.COLUMN_NAME='REGION_ID' 
    and D.TABLE_NAME='COUNTRIES' 
    and k.constraint_type='R'
)  t,
user_constraints v 
where t.R_constraint_name=v.constraint_name;
```

[image]

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 2):

Problem is here:

```
select * 
from  (select d.column_name,
              k.*,              --> this
              d.*               --> this
       from user_constraints k,
            user_cons_columns d 
       where k.constraint_name = D.CONSTRAINT_NAME
         and D.COLUMN_NAME = 'REGION_ID' 
         and D.TABLE_NAME = 'COUNTRIES' 
         and k.constraint_type='R'
       ) t,
       user_constraints v 
where t.R_constraint_name = v.constraint_name;
```

As both tables contain columns with same column names (in this case, it is the `constraint_name` column), Oracle can't tell which ones you're selecting. You should select columns you're interested in and - if they share the same name - use **aliases**.

For example:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from  (select d.column_name,
  3                k.r_constraint_name,
  4                k.table_name,
  5                d.constraint_name   d_constraint_name,     --> this
  6                k.constraint_name   k_constraint_name      --> this
  7         from user_constraints k,
  8              user_cons_columns d
  9         where k.constraint_name = D.CONSTRAINT_NAME
 10           and D.COLUMN_NAME = 'DEPTNO'
 11           and D.TABLE_NAME = 'DEPT'
 12           and k.constraint_type='R'
 13         ) t,
 14         user_constraints v
 15  where t.R_constraint_name = v.constraint_name;

no rows selected

SQL>
```